# android webview automatic send enter key on google site

Tags: android, webview, enter

Have a little program with a WebView loading e.g. "www.google.com". I have tried to start searching automatic without ENTER by user, after scanning a barcode, like this:

```
final String scanedCode = "123456";
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(100, scanedCode, 1, 0));
        dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
    }
);
```

The number "123456" will displayed in google search field, but the ENTER, or rather the automatic search is not started.

Have tried many ways and searched here, but I still cannot get these simple thing. Could someone give me some tips?

Comment: It is possible to run your own JS code programmatically inside a WebView. I think JS would be a more robust approach, you can also make sure the correct component has focus before sending the keys

Comment: Can I embed JS into google site?

Comment: Since you are embedding JS directly into the WebView, it will not care which URL is currently loaded inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more robust approach will be to inject your own javascript code directly into the WebView. This injection does not care which URL is loaded inside, so you can do it to any site.

It sounds like a big security hole but this really isn't. The browser is inside your app which means **you** are the browser therefore you can do anything you want while parsing the HTML code of the websites you're showing.

Here is a code example which loads some JS into a google hosted page:

```
final WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.browser);  
/* JavaScript must be enabled if you want it to work, obviously */  
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  

/* WebViewClient must be set BEFORE calling loadUrl! */  
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
   @Override  
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
   {  
       webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
            "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color = 'red'; " +  
            "})()");  
   }  
});  

 webview.loadUrl("http://code.google.com/android");
```

If you can run your own JS you can pretty much do anything you want - including traversing the DOM directly, accessing the search-box itself and making sure it has focus.

In order to figure out which JS code you want to inject, use Google Chrome on your PC and open google.com inside Chrome Developer Tools. Then try to type JS commands in the console until you get the required result. Typing JS lines in the console = injecting JS code into the page.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I got this with something like myWebview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementById('tsbb').click()})()");